iOS Share extension from Notes app, need to collect Text and Images simultaneously
From iPhone Notes app I need to collect both text and images to share in my main app. There can be three cases.

User can share both text and images simultaneously.
User can share only text.
User can share only images.

In my code I can share only image or text. When the notes app contains images and Texts both, my code does not work and share extension hangs. I need ways for case one to handle where when user share both text and images document from notes app I need to collect them.
My Code
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Vision
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

class ShareViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard
            let extensionItem = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem,
            let itemProvider = extensionItem.attachments?.first else {
            close()
            return
        }
        
        let textDataType = UTType.plainText.identifier
        
        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(textDataType) {
            // Handle text
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: textDataType, options: nil) { (providedText, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.close()
                    return
                }
                
                if let text = providedText as? String {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.displayShareView(with: text)
                    }
                } else {

                }
            }
            
        } else {
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            
            // Iterate over input items from the extension context
            for item in self.extensionContext!.inputItems as! [NSExtensionItem] {
                for provider in item.attachments! {
                    let itemProvider = provider
                    
                    // Handle image items (use UTType.image.identifier)
                    if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.image.identifier) {
                        group.enter()
                        itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.image.identifier, options: nil) { (result, error) in
                            if let error = error {
                                print("Error loading image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                group.leave()
                                return
                            }
                            
                            if let resultURL = result as? NSURL {
                                print("Received image URL: \(resultURL)")
                                if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: resultURL as URL), let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                                    print("Processing image for text...")
                                    self.processImageForText(image)
                                } else {
                                    print("Failed to load image data.")
                                }
                            } else {
                                print("No image URL found.")
                            }
                            group.leave()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // Once all operations are completed, complete the extension request
            group.notify(queue: .main) {
               // self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
    // Process image for text using Vision (OCR)
    private func processImageForText(_ image: UIImage) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
                print("Failed to convert UIImage to CGImage.")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.close()
                }
                return
            }
            
            let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: [:])
            let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest { (request, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("OCR error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.close()
                    }
                    return
                }
                
                let recognizedText = request.results?.compactMap { result in
                    (result as? VNRecognizedTextObservation)?.topCandidates(1).first?.string
                }.joined(separator: "\n") ?? "No text found in image"
                
                print("Recognized text from image: \(recognizedText)")
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.displayShareView(with: recognizedText)
                }
            }
            
            do {
                try requestHandler.perform([request])
            } catch {
                print("Failed to perform text recognition: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.close()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Display the SwiftUI view with the given text
    private func displayShareView(with text: String) {
        let contentView = UIHostingController(rootView: ShareExtensionView(text: text, onSave: { [weak self] savedText, title  in
            self?.handleSaveAction(with: savedText, title: title)
        }))
        self.addChild(contentView)
        self.view.addSubview(contentView.view)
        
        // Set up constraints
        contentView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    // Close the Share Extension
    func close() {
        self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    private func handleSaveAction(with text: String, title: String) {
        // Save text to shared container
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.aibuddy.aibuddyshareextention")
        userDefaults?.set(text, forKey: "sharedTextFromExtensionText")
        userDefaults?.set(title, forKey: "sharedTextFromExtensionTitle")
        userDefaults?.synchronize()

        // Prepare data to pass
        let title = title
        let encodedTitle = title.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
        let encodedText = text.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
        
        // Use a URL scheme to open the main app with parameters
        let urlScheme = "aibuddyshare://openFromShareExtension?title=\(encodedTitle)&text=\(encodedText)"
        
        // Ensure the URL scheme is valid before attempting to open
        if let url = URL(string: urlScheme) {
            print("Attempting to open the app with URL: \(url)")  // Debugging log

            // Attempt to open the app
            let _ = openURL(url)
            close()
        } else {
            print("Invalid URL scheme: \(urlScheme)")  // Log if URL is invalid
            self.close()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
        var responder: UIResponder? = self
        while responder != nil {
            if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
                return application.perform(#selector(openURL(_:)), with: url) != nil
            }
            responder = responder?.next
        }
        return false
    }

}


 let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
 var sharedText = ""
 var sharedImages: [UIImage] = []

  //Loop Through All Items
  for extensionItem in extensionItems {
        if let attachments = extensionItem.attachments {
            for attachment in attachments {
                let itemProvider = attachment
                
                // Handle Text
                if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.plainText.identifier) {
                    dispatchGroup.enter()
                    itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.plainText.identifier, options: nil) { (providedText, error) in
                        if let text = providedText as? String {
                            sharedText = text
                        }
                        dispatchGroup.leave()
                    }
                }
                
                // Handle Images
                if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.image.identifier) {
                    dispatchGroup.enter()
                    itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.image.identifier, options: nil) { (result, error) in
                        if let url = result as? URL, let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                            sharedImages.append(image)
                        }
                        dispatchGroup.leave()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

Loop through all the items and add them to an array. Once the loop finishes. OCR the images and display them in the view.

Thanks. I will let you know if it works.
